# OData protocol for iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5, protocols, odata

I'm using [**OData** protocol](http://msopentech.azurewebsites.net/odataorg/libraries/ios/)  to produce uniform and easy-to-consume data APIs.

I would like to know, Is OData protocol available for **iOS6** ?.

I got many **Apple LLVM Compiler issues** (more than 300) when I builded the current version.

I think the latest OData framework wrote in **iOS 4.1**.

Im using **Xcode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a)** with **iOS6 ARC enabled**.

I have attached the screenshot.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: why a negative vote now?? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded and checked the issue.

They are using custom setters and getters for their properties.

In their code they written something like:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain,getter=getEdmType,setter=setEdmType) NSString *m_EdmType;
```

Which causes issue, because for setter we need to pass an argument. So compiler expects a **`:`** after the custom setter name.

The compiler displayes the error: `ODataSDKV1-1.3/framework/src/MSODataLib/Interfaces/mProperties.h:39:67: Method name referenced in property setter attribute must end with ':'`

Change it to:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain,getter=getEdmType,setter=setEdmType:) NSString *m_EdmType;
```